# Clean form input to lowercase alphabetical using php

Tags: php, forms, get

I have a simple php file with a GET from a form to throw up some files from a directory. Quite simple code but I just need to strip from the string ANY characters that are NOT lowercase alpha. How would I go about doing that? (I'm a novice).

Here 'tis:

```
<?php $text = $_GET['text_string']; ?>

<form method="GET" action="index.php">Please enter some letters: <input type="text" name="text_string" value=""/> and hit <input type="submit" value="enter" />
</form>

<?php /* Split characters into an array */ $array = str_split($text); ?>

<?php foreach($array as $char) : ?>
   <img src="glyphs/<?php print ($char); ?>.jpg"/>
<?php endforeach ; ?>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To lowercase (note that you also can use [mb_strtolower](http://php.net/mb_strtolower) for better charset handling, but in this case you're only going to keep ASCII chars anyway so [strtolower](http://php.net/strtolower) is enough):

```
$text = strtolower($text);
```

To remove all non-alpha chars using [preg_replace](http://php.net/preg_replace):

```
$text = preg_replace('/[^a-z]/', '', $text);
```

Comment: No matter how many times I see regex it *still* looks like magic... +1 =)

Comment: ah! Thanks Emil :-) After writing this post I realised that perhaps I should also convert UC to LC... do you know how I would do this?

Comment: Still creating glyphs j-z but here is the unstyled thing: http://alphabeta.nielsoeltjen.com/index.php